# What does it mean for a function to be invertible 'almost everywhere'

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

It seems to me that the correct definition of a measure-theoretic inverse for a function f is a function g such that $f \circ g$ and $f \circ g$ are the identity almost everywhere. The problem I have with this definition is that this doesn't seem to identify itself with a category theoretic inverse (if we identify measurable functions equal almost everywhere, this doesn't form a quotient category). Furthermore, I do not believe measure preserving transformations invertible almost everywhere need not have an inverse which is measure preserving. What are some alternate/'correct' definitions of an 'almost everywhere inverse'.

Comment: Composition of Borel functions is well-defined in the sense that the equivalence class of the result does not depend on which of the Borel representatives you choose. Is the difficulty just from choosing only Lebesgue measurable representatives? But in general these cannot be composed in the first place...

Comment: Is "inventively" a typo?

Comment: Did you intend to say "$f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are the identity almost everywhere"?

Comment: That you cannot compose equivalence classes of almost equal functions is exactly what I mean that almost everywhere invertibility does not have a category theoretic inverse.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me - I've corrected the typo